# "AttributeError: 'GridFS' object has no attribute 'find'"

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I am using pymongo version 2.6.3, I am saving file in mongo in gridfs, suddenly gridfs is giving error. 
**AttributeError: 'GridFS' object has no attribute 'find'**
my code is:

```
import gridfs
admin_db = MDB_CONN['admin']
admin_db.authenticate(mongo_admin, mongo_password)
db = MDB_CONN["dbname"]
grid = gridfs.GridFS(db,collection="collectionName")
grid_cursor = grid.find({'file_hash':self.object_id},timeout=False, limit=1)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is [no `find()` method](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.6.3/api/gridfs/index.html) in version 2.6.3 of the driver; it was [added in version 2.7](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.7rc0/changelog.html#changes-in-version-2-7):

> PyMongo 2.7 is a major release with a large number of new features and
>   bug fixes. Highlights include:
>
> - Full support for MongoDB 2.6.
> - A new bulk write operations API.
> - Support
>     for server side query timeouts using max_time_ms().
> - Support for
>     writing aggregate() output to a collection.
> - A new parallel_scan()
>     helper.
> - OperationFailure and its subclasses now include a details
>     attribute with complete error details from the server.
> - **A new GridFS
>     find() method that returns a GridOutCursor.**
> - Greatly improved support
>     for mod_wsgi when using PyMongo’s C extensions. Read Jesse’s blog post
>     for details.
> - Improved C extension support for ARM little endian.

You should upgrade your driver to the latest supported version.